# Unable to pass swift implementation of kotlin interface to kotlin native

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I have an interface `SampleInterface` in `CommonMain`

```
interface SampleInterface {
  fun printMessage(message: String)
}
```

and a singleton object `Singleton` in `CommonMain`

```
object Singleton {
  private var interfaceObj: SampleInterface? = null
  fun setup(interfaceObj: SampleInterface) {
    this.interfaceObj = interfaceObj
  }

  fun printMessage(message: String) {
    this.interfaceObj?.printMessage(message)
  }
}
```

I am trying to Implement the interface `SampleInterface` in `swift`

```
class IosImpl: SampleInterface {
  func printMessage(message: String) {
    print("\(message)")
  }
}
```

passing the `IosImpl` object from `swift` to `Singleton` in `kotlin native`

```
func test() {
  let iImpl = IosImpl()
  Singleton().setup(iImpl) // Failing with KotlinException
}
```

Exception:

```
Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.native.concurrent.InvalidMutabilityException: mutation attempt of frozen
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the result of trying to mutate Kotlin's singleton.
 In Kotlin/Native, there are strict immutability rules, and one of them states that every object is `mutable XOR shared`. To achieve this, for singleton `object`s and enums are "frozen" by default - this means every attempt to mutate them will finish with `InvalidMutabilityException`, as you got. To avoid this, one got to make sure that `object` is thread-local and will never be mutated from another thread. 
 To read more on this theme, I recommend you to take a look at [Immutability](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/IMMUTABILITY.md) description on the K/N Github, and also the [Concurrency](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/CONCURRENCY.md#object-transfer-and-freezing) one.

Comment: Hey Artyom, Is there a way to mutate a property of shared singleton without making it Thread-local ?

Comment: I think it is not an option, because of the language limitation. Maybe one can figure something useful by using `AtomicReference`, and it surely depends on what's the purpose of this code.